# Word by word in mongoose.find

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a route like this:

```
router.get("/search/:value", function(req, res){
  Imgs.find({tags: req.params.value}, function(err, f){
    if(err){
      console.log(err); 
    } else {
      res.render("Images/index.ejs", {
        playlists: f
      }); 
    }
  });
});
```

Image schema

```
    title: String,
    image: String,
    description: String,
    tags: [

    ]
```

When the user adds an image he has the option to add tags to it, I'm trying to find an image based on its tags.

I have added a search box to a page.

The problem: 
I only can find images that have the exact same tags.

Is there any way that I can search word by word?

EDIT 1: 
Hi guys, i dont think i explained the problem correctly, i was really tired, sorry.

The Problem 2:
When i write in the search box, for example:
"*Rain Florest*"

The value that i will got is "*Rain Florest*" as a sentence, but i want to search for images that have the tags "*Rain*" or/and "*Florest*"

**FINAL EDIT**
I used the search value and then applied to the selected answer.

```
var arrayOfTags = req.params.value;
Imgs.find({tags: new RegExp(arrayOfTags, 'i')}, function(err, f){
    if(err){
      console.log(err); 
    } else {
      res.render("Images/index.ejs", {
        user: req.user,
        playlists: f
      }); 
    }
  });
});
```

Thank you guys !!

Comment: Please also provide the relevant part of your Image schema.

Comment: I did it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regex` to match sub-strings in tags like this:

```js
router.get("/search/:value", function(req, res){

  Imgs.find({tags: new RegExp(req.params.value, 'i')}, function(err, f){
    if(err){
      console.log(err); 
    } else {
      res.render("Images/index.ejs", {
        playlists: f
      }); 
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 var arrayOfTags=['tag1','tag2','tag3']
 Imgs.find({tags: {$in : arrayOfTags}}, function(err, f){
    if(err){
      console.log(err); 
    } else {
      res.render("Images/index.ejs", {
        playlists: f
      }); 
    }
    });
```

This will return all the 'Images' that have at least one of the tags in the array. But you probably want to get the array from query parameters like this :

```
 var arrayOfTags = req.query.tags
```

Comment: Hello, it didn't worked at all, but helped me solving it, thank you.